# Cocos2d-x extensions in an Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, xcode, cocos2d-x

I'm having trouble using `CCHttpRequest` in an Android app that's part of a Cocos2d-x project. Specifically I get a bunch of build errors when building in Eclipse that I don't get when building the iOS app in Xcode.

An example build error that I receive in Eclipse (but not in Xcode) is:

```
`Type 'CCHttpResponse' could not be resolved`
```

This error is for the line:

```
CCHttpResponse *response = (CCHttpResponse *)data;
```

Both Eclipse and Xcode projects reference the same `.cpp` files. To make the Eclipse project aware of the Cocos2d-x extensions I did the following:

1. Open Project => Properties => C/C++ General => Paths and Symbols => Source Location
2. Click `Link Folder...`
3. Check `Link to folder in the file system`
4. Browse to the folder containing the extensions (that work in the Xcode project)
5. Click Ok, Apply, and Ok

Note there are some other surprising errors in my `HelloWorldScene.cpp` file. For example:

`Symbol 'vector' could not be resolved`.

I'm guessing the problem is related to how I've set-up something in Eclipse. Since I'm new to Eclipse I'm not sure what to try. Everything builds and runs fine in the Xcode project.

**Edit #1**: After commenting the code responsible for most of the Eclipse build errors I noticed the error:

```
`make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libgame.so] Error 1`
```

I don't know what this means but it seems like it might be a more fundamental error than unresolved symbols.

**Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/StringHelper.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes                   

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static cocos_extension_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) \
$(call import-module,cocos2dx) \
$(call import-module,extensions)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1
```

Comment: have you created this project using `create_project.py` command or manual ?

Comment: Neither. I used the create android shell script that comes with Cocos2d-x.

Comment: ok. I think cocos2d library is not loading its classes. can you post text of `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` file which is in `jni` folder.

Comment: Ok posted Android.mk and Application.mk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` have some problem, Because in my application  `Android.mk` is loading more files, and my application is running properly in both platform android and ios. You can see the differences.. it may help you. I am also using `cocos2dx` library.

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/FixPhotoScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/SplashScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/TableViewTest.cpp\
                   ../../Classes/ProcessImage.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/TestUI.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosdenshion_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += box2d_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += chipmunk_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,cocos2dx)
$(call import-module,cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libcurl)
$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android)
$(call import-module,extensions)
$(call import-module,external/Box2D)
$(call import-module,external/chipmunk)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1
```

Comment: Changing the LOCAL_MODULE and LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME to the values you have seems to have helped. Although I also added /usr/include/c++/4.2.1 to the GNU C++ includes in Eclipse. Also I did project->index->rebuild a few times. Also I closed and re-opened Eclipse. Some combination of the above works :-)

Comment: Actually it seems like chaning LOCAL_MODULE and LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME back to my original values was necessary.